# Java process command result fail to capture result

Tags: java, linux, shell, process

I have a java program it does execute the shell command then wait for command to exit from shell to get result. But Process unable to read the output from command it just print result empty.

However same command if I run from shell prompt I could see result printing there..

{

[root@localhost home]# tsp -I marker input.mpg -P marker -a 10 -v 10 -O file output.mpg

- marker: 10
- marker: 20
- marker: 30
- marker: 40
- marker: 50
- marker: 60
- marker: 70
- marker: 80
- marker: 90
- marker: 100
- marker: OK
  [root@localhost home]#

}

Java program to execute shell command here 
{

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteShellComand {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();

    String command = "tsp -I olesmarker input.mpg -P " + "olesmarker -a 10 -v 10 -O file output.mpg";

    String output = obj.executeCommand(command);

    System.out.println("Command Result = " + output);

}

private String executeCommand(String command) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your "tsp" program is generating these "marker" progress messages to standard out? Some programs are using the shell standard err channel. Especially programs doing conversions (the '-O file output.mpg' kind of indicates such a functionality) often use the shell-std.out as default output for conversion result and the shell-sdt.err for status and progress messages. (very useful for connecting commands with pipes on the shell).

I would suggest to try

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

instead of

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: You are right.. tsp is writing to standard err channel . I changed the program to get it from ErrorStream. and it started printing in my java program.  Thanks a lot